# Vue.js app Maximum Call stack error after opening dialog few times

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dialog, vuetify.js

I have problem with my Vue.js app. I implemented data table and content is from API call. So after app is mounted, I call this API and fill Array with response, then show this data in table. I want to add possibility to add note to each row, so I will need to open dialog box and parse ID to it to be able to save note to that specific row.
I was able to implement this dialog box, currently without ID, so every row is same and when I click on save it's only close card, but I am facing problem that I want to resolve before continuing.

So problem is that when I click on that button to open Dialog, I can see that background is really blurry, like in picture below.

[image: DIALOG BOX]

When I click save and open this dialog again, or maybe two more times, I receive this error and page is not responding, I need to open new tab and go to same link.

[image: Console error]

This is my code for history component, where I have every button.

```
<v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="history"
          :search="search"
          class="elevation-1"
        >
          <template v-slot:item.recording>
            <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="400px">
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <v-btn
                  icon
                  small
                  @click="dialog = true"
                  v-bind="attrs"
                  v-on="on"
                >
                  <v-icon small> mdi-content-save</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </template>
              <NoteToHistoryDialog :noteId="noteId" v-on:close-card="dialog = false" />
            </v-dialog>
            <v-btn icon small @click="downloadAttachment">
              <v-icon small> mdi-download</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
```

Here is NoteToHistoryDialog component code.

```
<template>
  <v-main>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title class="primary white--text">{{  $t("Add Note") }}{{ noteId }}</v-card-title>
          <v-form>
            <v-text-field
                color="primary"
                label="Text"
                class="pr-4 pl-4"
                v-model="note"
            >
            </v-text-field>
          </v-form>
      <v-card-actions class="justify-end">
        <v-btn depressed plain color="primary white--text" @click="$emit('close-card')">
          {{ $t("Close") }}
          <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn depressed plain color="primary white--text" @click="addNote">
          {{  $t("Save") }}
          <v-icon>mdi-content-save</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-main>
</template>
```

But this should be OK.

Here is also picture of whole component. Dialog is triggered after clicking on that small diskete.

[image: Component]

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: You are creating a lot of v-dialogs. One for each row and all have the same v-model so they all open at once. That's the cause of the blurry background. I don't know if fixing this also fixes the error in the console, but you should definitely change this.

Comment: How can I change that? should I use v-model like this? ==> v-model="dialog" + id?

Comment: You should have only one `v-dialog` and feed it with the info of the selected item from the `v-data-table`.

Comment: So I need to move **v-dialog** before **v-data-table** and just give it info from **v-data-table**.. Correct? Or if its possible, can you give some example how it should looks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem, I created new component, copied and pasted whole CRUD table from Vuetify docs and edited line by line everything to my personal needs and now I can click on "Add Note" button as many times as I want and it will work without problem.

Here is working code.

```
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="history"
          sort-by="date"
          class="elevation-1"
        >
          <template v-slot:top>
            <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
              <v-card>
                <v-card-title class="primary white--text">
                  <span class="text-h5">{{ $t("Add Note") }}</span>
                </v-card-title>

                <v-card-text>
                  <v-container>
                    <v-row>
                      <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="12">
                        <v-form>
                          <v-textarea
                            color="primary"
                            label="Text poznámky"
                            v-model="editedItem.note"
                            auto-grow
                            clearable
                            >
                          </v-textarea>
                        </v-form>
                      </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                  </v-container>
                </v-card-text>

                <v-card-actions>
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                  <v-btn color="primary" text @click="close">
                    Zrušiť
                  </v-btn>
                  <v-btn color="secondary" text @click="save">
                    Uložiť
                  </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
            </v-dialog>
            <v-dialog v-model="dialogDelete" max-width="500px">
              <v-card>
                <v-card-title class="text-h5"
                  >Chcete stiahnuť nahrávku?</v-card-title
                >
                <v-card-actions>
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                  <v-btn color="primary" text @click="closeDelete"
                    >Zrušiť</v-btn
                  >
                  <v-btn color="secondary" text @click="deleteItemConfirm"
                    >OK</v-btn
                  >
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
            </v-dialog>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:item.recording="{ item }">
            <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="addNote(item)">
              mdi-content-save
            </v-icon>
            <v-icon small @click="downloadRecording(item)">
              mdi-download
            </v-icon>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
```